# Нужно получить шрифт из QFontComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю текстовый редактор. Нужно чтобы при изменении значения в QFontComboBox* FStyleList в текстовоее поле QTextEdit* MainTextEdit устанавливался нужный шрифт. Есть фрагмент кода.

в главном классе:

```
Fontstr = new QString (this);
MainTextEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
MainTextEdit->setMinimumSize(300, 300);

FStyleList = new QFontComboBox(this);

connect (FStyleList, SIGNAL(valueChanged()), this, SLOT(fontChanged(QString)));
```

описание функции:

```
void MainClass::fontChanged(Fontstr){
    QTextCursor cursor = MainTextEdit->textCursor();
    MainTextEdit->selectAll();
    Fontstr = FStyleList->currentFont().toString();
    MainTextEdit->setFontFamily(font.fromString(&fontstr));
    cursor.clearSelection();
    MainTextEdit->setFont(font);
}
```

В заголовчном файле:

```
class MainClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QFontComboBox *FStyleList;
    QFont *font;
    QString *Fontstr;
    QTextEdit *MainTextEdit;
private slots:
    void fontChanged(QString Fontstr);
```

ошибки:

при определении Fontstr в главном классе

> conversion from 'MainClass* const' to 'QChar' is ambiguous

В описании функции

> variable or field 'fontChanged' declared void

и

> "Fontstr" was not declared in this scope

Помогите исправить эти ошибки и корректно получить значение из QFontComboBox и установить его в QTextEdit

Скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание слота

```
void MainClass::setTextEditFont(const QFont& f){
QFont newFont = f;


newFont.setPixelSize(FontsizeSpin->value());
MainTextEdit->setFont(newFont);
```

Подключение слота

```
  connect(FStyleList, SIGNAL (currentFontChanged(const QFont&)), this, 
  SLOT(MainClass::setTextEditFont(const QFont&)));
```

Comment: Рекомендую смотреть справку по сигналам, слотам и так далее. У QFontComboBox нет сигнала valueChanged. Значит, смотрите. В QtCreator есть закладка `Справка`, переходите в нее и в самом верху выбираете `Указатель`, чуть ниже появляется поле `Искать` в которое вы можете вводить имена классов и методов

Comment: я лично для чтения документации предпочитаю doc.qt.io. контекстный поиск из креатора работает немного странно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти два виджета прекрасно подходят друг к другу с точки зрения установки шрифта:

```
connect(FStyleList, SIGNAL(currentFontChanged(const QFont&)), MainTextEdit, SLOT(setCurrentFont(const QFont&)));
```

Слот QTextEdit::setCurrentFont изменят шрифт у выделенного текста, если же необходимо изменить шрифт у всего документа, то надо использовать метод QWidget::setFont:

```
// коннект через лямбду
connect(FStyleList, &QFontComboBox::currentFontChanged, [&](const QFont& f)
{
    MainTextEdit->setFont(f);
});
```

**Дополнение**. Если необходимо устновить шрифт в QTextEdit с учетом других параметров (например, размер шрифта). Где-то в классе приложения создаем слот, например setTextEditFont(const QFont&), соответственно:

```
//В конструкторе
connect(FStyleList, &QFontComboBox::currentFontChanged, this, &MainClass::setTextEditFont);

//В слоте
void MainClass::setTextEditFont(const QFont& f)
{
    QFont newFont = f;

    // Учитываем размер шрифта
    newFont.setPixelSize(/*виджет с размером шрифта*/);
    // Устанавливаем новый шрифт в QTextEdit (для выделенного текста)
    MainTextEdit->setCurrentFont(newFont);

    // Или глобально, для всего текста в MainTextEdit
    // MainTextEdit->setFont(newFont);

}
```

Comment: А описание функции и QString удалить?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH да, ваш коннект и все, что с ним связано можете удалить

Comment: Мне ошибку выдает, что где-то в вашем connect нет точки с запятой вместо MainTextEdit

Comment: @Konstantin_SH да, небыло. Теперь есть )

Comment: Приложение работает, но шрифт не меняется

Comment: @Konstantin_SH а если после установки шрифта начать набирать текст в QTextEdit?

Comment: Добавляю скриншот

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91540/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-konstantin-sh).